# Given $x \in {\rm int}(K)$ (covered by nondecreasing cones $\{K^r\}$), does there exist $r_0$ s.t. $x \in {\rm int}(K^{r_0})$?

Tags: geometry, optimization, convex-cone

Let $K\ (\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n)$ be a closed convex cone and $\{K^r\}_{r=0}^\infty$ be a family of closed convex cones satisfying $K^r \subseteq K^{r+1} \subseteq K\ (\forall r)$.

Assume that ${\rm int}(K) \subseteq \bigcup_{r=0}^\infty K^r$ and there exists $x \in {\rm int}(K)$.

Then, does there exist $r_0$ such that $x \in {\rm int}(K^{r_0})$?

Besides, can we remove the assumption that $\{K^r\}$ are closed?

Intuitively, this proposition is true, but I cannot prove it rigorously. Note that a similar problem appears in the proof of Theorem 6.1 in the following paper: https://www.jstor.org/stable/25151657?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a round-about way of proving it, but it works. (There's probably a more straightforward way of doing this.)

First note that almost all of the cones $K_0,K_1,\dots$ must have non-empty interior. (Indeed, it is impossible for all of them to have empty interior, so there must exist an index $j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\operatorname{int}(K_r)\neq\emptyset$ for every $r\geq j$.)

Now let $x\in\operatorname{int}(K)$. We want to show that there exists an index $r_0\in\mathbb{N}$ for which $x\in\operatorname{int}(K_{r_0})$. By the assumption that $$\operatorname{int}(K)\subseteq\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{N}} K_r,$$ there is an index $r_1\in\mathbb{N}$ for which $x\in K_{r_1}$. By the observation in the preceeding paragraph, we may suppose without loss of generality that $\operatorname{int}(K_{r_1})$ is non-empty. If $x\in\operatorname{int}(K_{r_1})$ then we are done, so suppose that $x\not\in\operatorname{int}(K_{r_1})$. (That is, $x$ is on the boundary of $K_{r_1}$.) There exists a vector $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$x-y\in\operatorname{int}(K_{r_1}) \qquad\text{and}\qquad x+y\not\in K_{r_1}.$$ As $x\in\operatorname{int}(K)$, there exists a value $\epsilon>0$ small enough such that $x+\epsilon y\in\operatorname{int}(K)$. Define a new point $x_1=x+\epsilon y$. For this new point $x_1\in\operatorname{int}(K)$, there exists an index $r_0\in\mathbb{N}$ with $r_0>r_1$ such that $x_1\in K_{r_0}$. As it is the case that $$x-y\in\operatorname{int}(K_{r_1}) \qquad\text{and}\qquad K_{r_1}\subseteq K_{r_0},$$ it follows that $x-y\in\operatorname{int}(K_{r_0})$ as well. Every nontrivial convex combination of the points $x_1\in K_{r_0}$ and $x-y\in\operatorname{int}(K_{r_0})$ must be in $\operatorname{int}(K_{r_0})$. That is, for every $t\in(0,1)$, it holds that
$$tx_1 + (1-t)(x-y)\in\operatorname{int}(K_{r_0}).$$
Choosing $t = \frac{1}{1+\epsilon}$ gives us the desired result that $x\in\operatorname{int}(K_{r_0})$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Based on this proof, it seems that we can get the conclusion without assuming the closedness of $\{K^r\}$.

Comment: I suppose so. But the fact that the cones iareclosed is what makes the proof difficult. (If almost all of the cones we're open, for example, the statement would be trivially true.)